# building script with timestamp for batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm working on a new project and it requires a timestamp I have been reading up on this, and I 'm finding that it's easier with other language, but would ready like to intergrade this to my script

This is my current filename.txt file and this is how it looks

```
New folder 1\filename.txt
    {
      "action": "false",
      "timestamp": 0
    },
    {
      "action": "false",
      "timestamp": 0
    },
    {
      "action": "false",
      "timestamp": 0
    },
    {
      "action": "false",
      "timestamp": 0
    },
    {
      "action": "false",
      "timestamp": 0
    },
    {
      "action": "false",
      "timestamp": 0
    },
    {
      "action": "false",
      "timestamp": 0
    },
    {
      "action": "false",
      "timestamp": 0
    },
    {
      "action": "false",
      "timestamp": 0
    },
    {
      "action": "false",
      "timestamp": 0
    },
    {
      "action": "false",
      "timestamp": 0
    },
    {
      "action": "false",
      "timestamp": 0
    },
```

and this is the result I am looking for

```
New folder2\filename.txt
    {
      "action": "false",
      "timestamp": 1661126427
    },
    {
      "action": "false",
      "timestamp": 1661126427
    },
    {
      "action": "false",
      "timestamp": 1661126427
    },
    {
      "action": "false",
      "timestamp": 1661126427
    },
    {
      "action": "false",
      "timestamp": 1661126452 <--- it increases by 25 every 4 sets
    },
    {
      "action": "false",
      "timestamp": 1661126452
    },
    {
      "action": "false",
      "timestamp": 1661126452
    },
    {
      "action": "false",
      "timestamp": 1661126452
    },
    {
      "action": "false",
      "timestamp": 1661126477 <--- it increases by 25 every 4 sets
    },
    {
      "action": "false",
      "timestamp": 1661126477
    },
    {
      "action": "false",
      "timestamp": 1661126477
    },
    {
      "action": "false",
      "timestamp": 1661126477
    },
```

I have found this script that was shared but I am not sure the best way to link it to my current script

or if it can be made into it's own script to read any `*.txt` and to find the word  `"timestamp":`  and edit the file as needed, if it can edit the file directly in `New Folder 2` or it can copy from `New folder 1` to `New folder 2` this would be great as well

I would be intergrading this script or updates to my Choice Menu, in my script and have many more scripts that `call` and `goto`

```
@echo off
setlocal
call :GetUnixTime UNIX_TIME
echo %UNIX_TIME% seconds have elapsed since 1970-01-01 00:00:00
goto :EOF

:GetUnixTime
setlocal enableextensions
for /f %%x in ('wmic path win32_utctime get /format:list ^| findstr "="') do (
    set %%x)
set /a z=(14-100%Month%%%100)/12, y=10000%Year%%%10000-z
set /a ut=y*365+y/4-y/100+y/400+(153*(100%Month%%%100+12*z-3)+2)/5+Day-719469
set /a ut=ut*86400+100%Hour%%%100*3600+100%Minute%%%100*60+100%Second%%%100
endlocal & set "%1=%ut%" & goto :sub1
```

This was my idea, this is what I was trying to do

```
@ECHO Off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
cd /d "%~dp0"
:: Significant part of string

set "params1="timestamp": "
set "timestamp=%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%date:~-10,2%_%date:~-7,2%_%date:~-4,4%"

@For %%G In ("%~dp0Originals") Do Set "sourcedir=%%~fG"
@For %%G In ("%~dp0Ready") Do Set "destdir=%%~fG"
```

and then I was going to link the `timestamp` to my current script like this

```
:subs2
SET "original=%line%"
FOR /L %%s IN (0,1,9) DO set "line=!line:%params2%%%s=%params2%!"
IF "%original%" neq "%line%" goto subs2
set "line=!line:%params2%=%params2%%timestamp%!"  < ----- adding here
GOTO :eof
```

This area is the place I use to link changes or things I `set`

Please any help with this would be great

I have found many shared posts but I can't get the results I'm looking for

Comment: I would advise that you do not use batch files to edit other files, unless that batch file gets the assistance of a proper scripting language.

Comment: Thanks for the advise - the script I use is a `.bat` file and I use this for many things, and so far the results using my script has worked out for many task. but I never messed with a timestamp the way I was testing with `set=timestamp.....` works it gives me the dates and times etc, but for the goal in question it's a bit tricky was looking to intergrade it, or make it's own `.bat.` script that can edit the file, if there is a way to `set timestamp` to give the results that would be perfect

Comment: The point I was making is that you could make a PowerShell script, JScript or VBScript, instead of another batch file, and run that instead. Alternatively you could integrate the PS, VBS or JS into the batch file. There's no reason to create relatively complicated batch file code to perform a task it was never designed to do, especially when those other technologies can do it better. A batch file is essentially a one by one listing of individual commands, there's nothing to stop one or more of those commands from being the use of a more intuative or efficient, purpose built scripting language.

Comment: Yea, I know what you were saying, but the thing is I do not know anything else

Comment: If I only knew how to lay block paving, but not how to fit carpet, do you think I would be sat on the cold stone floor typing this comment? :-)

Comment: yes, I understand what your are saying, but with that it still takes time to learn, if I needed to get something done like carpeting I would hire someone to get it done today, instead of leaving my home with a concrete floor for weeks. so I can do it myself,  don't get me wrong I like learning and doing  things myself, but when I'm trying a new thing under a deadline, is the reason why I point to you'll. The project I'm working on is scheduled so time is not on my side, but OK, thanks I will see if can link something to a already made script

Answer (score 0):

Why not just generate the file instead of attempting to modify an existing file?

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "outfile=u:\outputfile.txt"

DEL "%outfile%" 2>nul
SET /p "blocks=How many blocks ? "
CALL :getunixtime

:newblock
(
FOR /L %%b IN (1,1,4) do (
 ECHO     {
 echo      "action": "false",
 echo      "timestamp": %unix_time%
 IF %blocks%%%b==14 (echo     }) ELSE (echo     },)
)
)>>"%outfile%"

SET /a blocks-=1
SET /a unix_time +=25
IF %blocks% gtr 0 GOTO newblock


TYPE "%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF

:: For testing, just return a constant time
:getunixtime
SET /a unix_time=1661126427

GOTO :EOF
```

So simple, no analysis is necessary.

Comment: `SET /a unix_time=1661126427` so in order to get a new timestamp I would need to change this number, the result was to show the current date and time so like today is `1661282410`

Comment: I'd suggest you use the `:GetUnixTime` subroutine from your first code posting in this question.

Comment: Thank you with your updated script it gave me ideas on how to upgrade mine and a few other scripts - I actually thought of an easier way to do the task at hand - Thank you